# How can I log the time of the execution of this terminal line?

Tags: bash

```
nohup mpirun -np 20 ./wrf.exe &> wrf.log &
```

I know that to get the timing of the ./wrf.exe is simply

```
(time ./wrf.exe) 2> time.txt
```

But I am not sure how to include the other two options (nohup and mpirun) along with the -np 20 within that line to actually output the log with the timing of the execution.

Comment: `(time nohup mpirun ...) 2>time.txt`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `2&>1` to get stderror and stdoutput both to a file. Since that is what you do, first command you place stdoutput in to a file and second command you place stderror to a file.